# Podman memlock limits

Tags: fedora, podman, fedora-silverblue

I'm evaluating Fedora Silverblue as my main development OS, I'd be using it with other developers that will be using either MacOS or other Linux distributions. I'll need to work with Docker containers.

Fedora comes with Podman as a rootless alternative to manage containers and it's supposed to have exactly the same interface as docker, so `alias docker=podman` should work.

I've also installed `podman-compose` to have `docker-compose` experience, it all works great but I am struggling with the following config to setup ELK stack:

```yaml
version: '3.3'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.7.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    networks:
      - elastic

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.7.0
    container_name: kibana
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://elasticsearch:9200
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://elasticsearch:9200
    networks:
      - elastic

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

While this works with Docker, it doesn't with Podman due to following config:

```yaml
ulimits:
  memlock:
    soft: -1
    hard: -1
```

I understand this works on Docker because it runs with high privileges and can set these limits to unlimited but because Podman is rootless and I run Silverblue these limits cannot be raised.

I've searched on how to increase ulimit with Podman, Silverblue but couldn't.

Are there any ways to increase these limits with Podman on Silverblue and make such `docker-compose` setup work with my system?

Comment: Im facing the exact same issue on mac m1 for podman-compose. It has something to do with podman capabilities permissions but not able to figure it out. were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you run Podman as rootless user then you are not allowed to set the ulimits higher than what your session currently has.

If you need to set a higher ulimit, you either need to allow your user to have it (tweaking /etc/security/limits.conf) or you run the container as root.